# Django adds an extra field to the GROUP BY clause

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Here is a query:

```
speed_by_computer = ChartPoint.objects.filter(
    date__gte=start,
    date__lt=end,
).values('computer_id') \
 .annotate(max_speed=Max('speed'))
```

Here is an SQL query produced by this query:

```
SELECT "computer_id", MAX("speed") AS "max_speed" 
FROM "api_chartpoint" 
WHERE (
    "date" >= 2018-05-17 08:00:00+00:00 AND 
    "date" < 2018-05-17 09:00:00+00:00
) 
GROUP BY "computer_id", "date" 
ORDER BY "date" DESC
```

Note that there is an unexpected `date` in the `GROUP BY` clause. Why is it here? Here is what I expected:

```
SELECT "computer_id", MAX("speed") AS "max_speed" 
FROM "api_chartpoint" 
WHERE (
    "date" >= 2018-05-17 08:00:00+00:00 AND
    "date" < 2018-05-17 09:00:00+00:00
) 
GROUP BY "computer_id"
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem was in the default ordering. It was specified in the `Meta`:

```
class ChartPoint(models.Model)
    ...
    class Meta:
       ordering = ['-date']
```

Remove the ordering and `date` will not be added to the `GROUP BY`:

```
speed_by_computer = ChartPoint.objects.filter(
    date__gte=start,
    date__lt=end,
).values('computer_id') \
 .annotate(hs_avg=Max('speed'))
 .order_by()
```